# implementing licensing in .net winform app

Tags: .net, licensing

How can i implement licensing application 
like 30 day trial
free

Comment: This question or ones like it have been asked so many times.  Search SO for ".net licensing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Most come down to two options:

1) Service That Handles Keys, Payments, Provisioning

2) Product

Here are solutions:

Microsoft Software Licensing and Protection Services:
http://www.microsoft.com/slps/ 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Software_Licensing_and_Protection_Services

Infralution Licensing System:
http://www.infralution.com/licensing.html

InstallShield:
http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm

Answer (score 1):

We are using [Manco .NET Licensing System](http://www.mancosoftware.com/licensing/index.htm) during several years (we are subscribers). Guys are quite responsive and provide good support level. The software itself is quite flexible and allows implementation of the different licensing approaches.

They have the ability to automate the licensing workflow online via a web server, use custom values and encryption/decryption for sensitive code. They are continuously updating it with improvements and features.

The latest update we get from Manco Software is cool. They added Silverlight based license shop to the Activation Web Service with no cost. So now our sale persons can issue keys from anywhere, just having PC with Windows and Internet Explorer.